# How does the graph shows horizontal tangency,but how?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image: a graph]. I am supposed to find critical numbers from this graph. I have read the solution. It says to find the critical numbers I have to find to horizontal tangency of the graph. I know that horizontal tangent has a slope of zero. and thats why the x-value of those points are the critical points. Atleast I hope I understand. But what is horizontal tangents and how come -5, -1 and 4 are horizontal tangents. I hope I don't sound stupid and I have made my question clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A horizontal tangent *line* is a *line* that is tangent to the curve at a point where $f'(x) = 0$.

Recall that the derivative of a point on a curve is the slope of the line tangent to that curve at that point.

For example, the horizontal line tangent to the curve at $(-5, f(-5)) = (-5, 3)$  just touches the curve. It is given, simply, by the equation of the line $y = f(-5) = $. 3(Recall that horizontal lines, having no slope, are all of the form $y = a$ for some constant a.

The values you give are not the equations of tangent lines. You need to write your tangent lines using equations $y = f(-5),\; y = f(-1), \;y = f(4)$.

Comment: how can you just look at the graph and say the f' is 0. you don't even know the equation yet?

Comment: There is a very helpful grid of the Cartesian plane which you can use to identify $f(x)$ for integer values of $x$. Example: when $x = -5$, identify $-5$ on the x-axis (5 units to the left of zero), and then to find $f(-5)$ travel vertically toward the curve. Where $x=-5$ meets the curve gives you the point $(x, f(x)=y)$, in this case, the point $(-5, 3)$. You can find that the y-value where the line x = -5 meets the curve by traveling horizontally toward the y-axis to see that indeed, the y value $f(-x) = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an horizontal tangent line has a slope equal to $0$. The slope of the tangent is given by the value of the first derivative. Then, if, at a point, $f'=0$ it means that $f$ (so the plot) goes through a local maximum or a local minimum.

Comment: how can you just look at the graph and say the f' is 0. you don't even know the equation yet?

Comment: I just notice that the tangent is horizontal and/or that there are maximum and minimum. Just take the curve of a sine and you will conclude the same.